# Create a group of numbers that does not exceed 34

Tags: r

I need to create groups of numbers which summed up do not reach 34.

For example: I have an array `x<-c(28,26,20,5,3,2,1)` and I need to create the following groups: `a=(28,5,1)`, `b=(26,3,2)`, `c=(20)` because the sums of the groups `a`, `b` and `c` do not exceed 34.

Is it possible to implement this procedure in R?

Comment: And why those specific groups?  the groups (28) (26) (20) (5) (3) (2) (1) don't exceed 34 either.

Comment: Do we have a minimum and maximum group size ?

Comment: @Dason. Because I have to create as little as possible groups that do not exceed 34. So the process I have to implement in the script is:
1. Sort the array in descending order
2. I take the largest number of the array
3. I add it to the next one
4. If the sum is greater than 34 I try to add the third and so on. If the sum is less than 34, however, I must add the third element because the sum could still be less than 34.
The philosophy of the script is to create the least possible number of groups that do not exceed 34

Comment: @MatteoBertazzoni My point was that you didn't specify that in your original question.  We aren't you so if you don't tell us the specifications then we won't know them.  Please modify your question to outline *all* of the requirements.

Comment: If you want the smallest number of groups, then this is known as the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). The [gbp package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbp/index.html) might be of relevance here.

Comment: Nice idea @ArtemSokolov! However after your suggestion I installed that package and played with it but couldn't figure out how to apply it to this question, I'd be interested in seeing a solution.

Comment: Note that this question is also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140990/why-my-rcpp-code-is-not-much-faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you want to do:

```
create_groups <- function(input, threshold) {
  input <- sort(input, decreasing = TRUE)
  result <- vector("list", length(input))
  sums <- rep(0, length(input))
  for (k in input) {
    i <- match(TRUE, sums + k <= threshold)
    if (!is.na(i)) {
      result[[i]] <- c(result[[i]], k)
      sums[i] <- sums[i] + k
    }
  }
  result[sapply(result, is.null)] <- NULL
  result
}

create_groups(x, 34)
# [[1]]
# [1] 28  5  1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 26  3  2
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 20
```

However it is not guaranteed that this greedy algorithm will output the optimal solution in terms of number of groups. For instance:

```
y <- c(18, 15, 11, 9, 8, 7)
create_groups(y, 34)
# [[1]]
# [1] 18 15
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 11  9  8
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 7
```

while the optimal solution in this case consists of only 2 groups: `list(c(18, 9, 7), c(15, 11, 8))`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all possible combinations of subsets of x that meet this condition, you can use

```
x = c(28,26,20,5,3,2,1)
y = lapply(seq_along(x), function(y) combn(x, y)) # list all combinations of all subsets
le34 = sapply(y, function(z) colSums(z) <= 34) # which sums are less than 34
lapply(seq_along(y), function(i) y[[i]][,le34[[i]]] ) # list of combinations that meet condition
```