# Why my Rcpp code is not much faster?

Tags: r, performance, rcpp

For practicing my C++, I'm trying to convert some R code to Rcpp.
The code is a greedy algorithm implemented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132629/6103040).

Next, see my Rcpp code (in a .cpp file), and some benchmark of the two codes:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List create_groups2(const NumericVector& x, double thr) {

  int n = x.size();
  List res(n);
  int c = 0;
  double sum;

  std::list<double> x2(n);
  std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), x2.begin()); // copy x in x2
  x2.sort(std::greater<double>()); // sort in descending order
  std::list<double>::iterator it;
  NumericVector x3(n);
  int i = 0, c2;

  while (x2.size()) {
    sum = 0; c2 = 0;
    for (it = x2.begin(); it != x2.end();) {
      if ((sum + *it) <= thr) {
        sum += *it;
        x3[i] = *it;
        i++; c2++;
        it = x2.erase(it);
        if (sum >= thr) break;
      } else {
        it++;
      }
    }
    res[c] = x3[seq(i - c2, i - 1)];
    c++; 
  }

  return res[seq_len(c) - 1];
}


/*** R
y <- c(18, 15, 11, 9, 8, 7)
create_groups2(sample(y), 34)

create_groups <- function(input, threshold) {
  input <- sort(input, decreasing = TRUE)
  result <- vector("list", length(input))
  sums <- rep(0, length(input))
  for (k in input) {
    i <- match(TRUE, sums + k <= threshold)
    if (!is.na(i)) {
      result[[i]] <- c(result[[i]], k)
      sums[i] <- sums[i] + k
    }
  }
  result[sapply(result, is.null)] <- NULL
  result
}

x_big <- round(runif(1e4, min = 1, max = 34))
all.equal(
  create_groups(x_big, 34), 
  create_groups2(x_big, 34)
)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  R = create_groups(x_big, 34), 
  RCPP = create_groups2(x_big, 34),
  times = 20
)
*/
```

For this type of problem (looping over and over a vector), I was expecting my Rcpp version to be much faster, but I get this result for the benchmark:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    R 584.0614 590.6234 668.4479 717.1539 721.9939 729.4324    20   b
 RCPP 166.0554 168.1817 170.1019 170.3351 171.8251 174.9481    20  a
```

**Any idea why my Rcpp code is not much faster than the R version?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting, but according to your table your Rcpp code is about four times faster than your R code. How much did you expect?

Comment: I was expecting the Rcpp version to be at least 20-100 times faster than the R version (*for this kind of problem*).

Comment: You're not doing much work in R. `sort`, `match`, `is.na`, `is.null`, `+`, `<=`... they're all pretty thin wrappers around compiled code.

Comment: Sorry to be the messenger of bad news, but that's unrealistic. A speed-up of about four times is a _very great improvement_. Even with hard-coded-assembly it couldn't be beaten significantly, I guess.

Comment: Basically, I expected an improvement because of the `for (k in input)` in R (loop over all elements) and that in my Rcpp version my `input` (`x2`) becomes smaller and smaller.

Comment: Of course, if you change the algorithms complexity from, say O(n²) to O(n*log n), you could expect a greater difference. But because of the algorithms complexity and **not** the language.

Comment: If you pre-allocate / define a size for `x3` and replace `x3.push_back(*it)` with `x3[i] = *it` (as an example only)  you *might* get some gain.

Comment: @zx485 Yes, I may not have been clear enough. For me changing the loop (in Rcpp) + the algorithm complexity should improve performance a lot.

Comment: [There is no Free Lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem). In my talks I sometimes show the simple (brute force) 'pi by simulation'.  Because the R code is already vectorized, the C++ is generally less than two times as fast.  You save on some overhead, and possible some sanity checks.

Comment: @SymbolixAU If i do `std::vector<double> x3; x3.reserve(n);` outside the while-loop and do only `x3.clear();` inside, it doesn't change the performance.

Comment: @SymbolixAU If I make `x3` a `NumericVector` of size `n` and fill that (incrementing the indices, see my edit), it also doesn't change performance, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, 70% of the times is used for ordering the list (`x2.sort(std::greater<double>());`). I think this is because lists are not contiguous data (as compared to a vector).

So, removing this line and using `create_groups2(sort(x_big, decreasing = TRUE), 34)` improve performance by 3, which makes the Rcpp version 9-11.5 times faster than the R version for `x_big` of size `1e4`-`1e5`.

This is better, but I was still expecting much more. I think my algorithm is still quadratic in the size of the input, this is why I can't get dramatic improvements.